# FileOp Failure on: /......./: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, permissions, joomla

im using cpanel when i changes the foler permission i got this error please help

FileOp Failure on: /home/public_html/components/com_openinviter: Operation not permitted

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't have permission to change the permissions (ironic, isn't it?)

If you own the directory the file is in, you can make a copy of it, delete the original, rename the copy to have the same name as the original, and change permissions on that.